# Get the indices of an array after sorting?

Tags: java

Suppose the user enter an array, for example:

```
Array = {France, Spain, France, France, Italy, Spain, Spain, Italy}
```

which I did know the length of it

the `index` array would be:

```
index = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Now, after sorting it using `Arrays.sort(Array);`

`newArray` will be like:

```
newArray = {France, France, France, Italy, Italy, Spain, Spain, Spain}
```

and the `newIndex` will be:

```
newIndex = {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 6}
```

The problem is: how can I find the `newIndex` from the input Array?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839915/sorting-a-list-based-on-another-lists-values-java/4839994#4839994 but much more clearly defined.

Comment: jfyi, here is how it looks with scala stdlib : input.zipWithIndex.sorted.map( _._2). A bit less efficient(you won't notice the differeentce in most of mundane cases) but painless.

Comment: So how do we sort one array & then based on its index, simultaneously move the values of another array of same length to respective indexes?

Making a pair would be the best option or is there a better alternative?

Note: these 2 arrays will be different int arrays and not indices.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Don't sort the array to start with. Sort the index array, passing in a comparator which compares values by using them *as* indexes into the array. So you end up with `newIndex` as the result of the sort, and it's trivial to go from there to the sorted array of actual items.

Admittedly that means sorting an array of integers in a custom way - which either means using an `Integer[]` and the standard Java library, or a 3rd party library which has an "IntComparator" interface which can be used in conjunction with a `sort(int[], IntComparator)` type of method.

EDIT: Okay, here's an example comparator. For the sake of simplicity I'll assume you only want to sort an "original" array of strings... and I won't bother with nullity testing.

```
public class ArrayIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    private final String[] array;

    public ArrayIndexComparator(String[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public Integer[] createIndexArray()
    {
        Integer[] indexes = new Integer[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            indexes[i] = i; // Autoboxing
        }
        return indexes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2)
    {
         // Autounbox from Integer to int to use as array indexes
        return array[index1].compareTo(array[index2]);
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
String[] countries = { "France", "Spain", ... };
ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(countries);
Integer[] indexes = comparator.createIndexArray();
Arrays.sort(indexes, comparator);
// Now the indexes are in appropriate order.
```

Answer (score 34):

Concise way of achieving this with Java 8 Stream API,

```
final String[] strArr = {"France", "Spain", "France"};
int[] sortedIndices = IntStream.range(0, strArr.length)
                .boxed().sorted((i, j) -> strArr[i].compareTo(strArr[j]) )
                .mapToInt(ele -> ele).toArray();
```

Comment: How do you sort it in reverse/descending order? If the array is of double datatype.

Comment: You would use compareTo method on top of Double

Comment: To sort it in reverse order, you just negate both comparing numbers.

Comment: If you don't mind using Integer[] then this nice code snipped can be simplified by removing the mapToInt operation...
    Integer[] sortedIndices =     IntStream.range(0, strArr.length)                 .boxed().sorted((i, j) -> strArr[i].compareTo(strArr[j]) ).toArray(Integer[]::new);

Answer (score 8):

```
TreeMap<String,Int> map = new TreeMap<String,Int>();
for( int i : indexes ) {
    map.put( stringarray[i], i );
}
```

Now iterator over map.values() to retrieve the indexes in sort order, and over map.keySet() to get the strings, or over map.entrySet() to get the String-index-Pairs.

Comment: This doesn't work due to duplicates. A SortedMultimap wouldn't help here.

Comment: @maaartinus It could be made to work with a map of TreeMap<String, LinkedList<Int>>. First you'd add all the strings to the map with empty lists, then you'd iterate through the original list and add the indices to the map item lists.

Comment: Then you'd simply iterate over values and insert an element for each index in the list... It'd be stable.

Comment: @ParthianShot Actually,  [`MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().linkedListValues().build()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html#treeKeys()) would do exactly that in a single pass.

Answer (score 6):

If having a scenario of repeatedly sorting primitive float or int arrays with positive values, then a method like below yields much better (x3~x4) speed compared to using any comparators:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {           
    float[] array = RandomUtils.randomFloatArray(-1,  1, 3000);
    long[] valueKeyPairs = new long[array.length]; 
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
        valueKeyPairs[j] = (((long) Float.floatToIntBits(array[j])) << 32) | (j & 0xffffffffL);
    }
    Arrays.sort(valueKeyPairs);
    /**Then use this to retrieve the original value and index*/
    //long l = valueKeyPairs[j];
    //float value = Float.intBitsToFloat((int) (l >> 32));
    //int index = (int) (l);
}
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

Comment: Nifty! Cute trick to stick the key into the lower bits of the value to be sorted.

Comment: Great trick! Also, you can use an unstable sort, the since the original ordering will order otherwise equal values.

Answer (score 3):

I made the following based on @Skeet's code. I think it is a little more OOPie. I dunno.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<Integer> sortIndex(List<T> in) {
    ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
        index.add(i);
    }

    Collections.sort(index, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer idx1, Integer idx2) {
            return in.get(idx1).compareTo(in.get(idx2));
        }
    });

    return index;
}
```

Instead of the class that implements the sorting and indexing having the Comparator code for the different objects coming in, the objects in the original array must implement the Comparable interface. It seems many objects of interest have a natural ordering and have the Comparable interface implemented already.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 9, 4, 1));
    // Just pass in the list to have its indexes sorted by the natural ordering
    List<Integer> idx = sortIndex(a1);

    List<Double> a2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1.0, 5.3, 5.2, -3.1, 0.3));
    idx = sortIndex(a2);

    List<numBits> a3 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a3.add(new numBits(i));
    }

    // If you need to sort the indexes of your own object, you must implement
    // the Comparable Interface.
    idx = sortIndex(a3);
}

static class numBits implements Comparable<numBits> {
    private int a;

    public numBits(int i) {
        a = i;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(a);
    }

    // Sort by the total number of bits in the number.
    @Override
    public int compareTo(numBits that) {
        if (Integer.bitCount(this.a) < Integer.bitCount(that.a))
            return -1;
        if (Integer.bitCount(this.a) > Integer.bitCount(that.a))
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this is to Wrap the original index and country name into a separate Class. Then sort the Array based on the names. This way, your original indexes will be preserved.

Comment: could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1):

What Comes at first Glance is Map them like that

```
Map <Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(0, "France");
map.put(1, "Spain");
map.put(2, "France");
```

and then sort them by value [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) and then you can know their indexes and values (key, values) just print the map

```
Iterator mapIterator = map.keySet().iterator();  

while (mapIterator .hasNext()) {  
     String key = mapIterator.next().toString();  
     String value = map.get(key).toString();  

     System.out.println(key + " " + value);  
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use foreach-loop? Why do you make it slower using keySet()and a lookup instead of entrySet()? Why do you output the values instead of making a method, which can be used further?

Answer (score 0):

i found solution.

```
List<String> a = {b, a, d, c};
List<Integer> b = {2, 1, 4, 3};
```

and if `a` sort

```
private void setsortb() {
List<String> beforeA = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> beforeB = new ArrayList<>();
beforeA.addAll(a);
beforeB.addAll(b);
a.sort();//change like this {a, b, c, d}

for(int i = 0; i < beforeA.size(); i++) {
int index = beforeA.indexOf(a.get(i));
b.set(i, beforeB.get(i));
}
}
```

like this

result

```
a = {a, b, c, d}
b = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```