# Index of each element after sorting

Tags: java, sorting, ranking

If we have array of element, what is the efficient way to calculate index of each element after sorting that array? is there any way to efficiently reuse `sort` function in `c++` or `java`?

for example:

```
double[] array=[".2",".6",".3",".5",".1"];
```

I want something like this:

```
         ans=  [  1,   4,   2,   3,   0 ];
```

that's because after sort `.2` place in index `1`, `.6` place in index `4`, `.3` place in index `2` and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array and keep track of the index in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587314/how-to-sort-an-array-and-keep-track-of-the-index-in-java)

Comment: that's a different question. I need to know index of each element after sort, but those algorithms provide index of each element in original array.

Comment: You need to encapsulate the original index of each element before the sort so that you can access it after the sort.

Comment: It won't help because in want to access rank of element by `O(1)` after sorting. I don't want to search for the element each time.

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish what you are looking for in `O(n log n)`, there most likely is a better way:

```
double[] arr = {0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1};
Integer[] intermediateIndices = new Integer[arr.length];
Integer[] finalIndices = new Integer[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  intermediateIndices[i] = i;
  finalIndices[i] = i;
}

Arrays.sort(intermediateIndices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return Double.compare(arr[o1], arr[o2]);
  }
});

Arrays.sort(finalIndices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return intermediateIndices[o1] - intermediateIndices[o2];
  }
});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intermediateIndices));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalIndices));

// [4, 0, 2, 3, 1]
// [1, 4, 2, 3, 0]
```