# java arrangement of lowest to highest on input values

Tags: java, sorting

Please help me got the code to arrange lowest to highest input values. Below is my sample code:

```
 System.out.print("Enter Number of Process: ");
 int p = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

 int [] arrival = new int[p];
 int [] size = new int[p];
 for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
 System.out.print("Arrival Time of Process #"+(i+1)+":");
 arrival[i]=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
```

The expected output must be:

> Enter Number of Process: 4
>   Arrival Time of Process # 1: 100
>   Arrival Time of Process # 2: 110
>   Arrival Time of Process # 3: 102
>   Arrival Time of Process # 4: 101
>   P1: 100
>   P4: 101
>   P3: 103
>   P2: 110

If you're familiar on `First Come First Serve Algorithm`, that was related on this.

Comment: You on the other hand, don't seem familiar with the "First Code Then Ask" policy.

Comment: Apology. Im now trying some codes for this output. Im just asking for some guide coz I thought there are many ways for that output. I just need a specific guide. Sorry again

Comment: Slightly improved readability and added extra tag

Comment: There is a typo in your post. You have input as 102, but output is 103.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you'd also like to keep track of the original indexes of the input values while doing the sorting. The thread I recommend you to read is [sorting pairs of (value, index) compared by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587314/how-to-sort-an-array-and-keep-track-of-the-index-in-java). Please try the following approach:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter Number of Process: ");
    int p = 0;

    try {
        p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
    }

    Pair[] arrival = new Pair[p];
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        System.out.print("Arrival Time of Process #" + (i + 1) + ":");
        try {

            arrival[i] = new Pair(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(arrival);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrival.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("P" + arrival[i].index + ": " + arrival[i].value);
    }
}

// a little change was made to the original code
public static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {

    public final int index;
    public final int value;

    public Pair(int index, int value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair other) {
        return Integer.valueOf(this.value).compareTo(other.value);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Enter Number of Process: 4
Arrival Time of Process #1:100
Arrival Time of Process #2:110
Arrival Time of Process #3:103
Arrival Time of Process #4:101
P1: 100
P4: 101
P3: 103
P2: 110
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. This is what i need :) not familiar on your used codes but I study that functions .

Comment: why above code if sort(arrival)? only the value sorted? not the index?

Comment: @JhayCee: The new class Pair does the trick. sorting is still based on values, but the original index is kept in the Pair class as a field.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-).

```
int[] is = {100, 110, 101, 102};
Arrays.sort(is);
for (int i : is) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Output:

```
100
101
102
110
```