# How do I get the index of sorted numbers from Arrays.sort in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to do descended sort with `Double` values.

```
Double[] test = {7.0, 2.0, -5.0, 5.0, 9.0};
Arrays.sort(test, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test)); // [9, 7, 5, 2, -5]
```

So far, it looks good. But I need to get the index for the sorting as well. How can I do that?

I know that the sorted index did go from `0 1 2 3 4` to `4 0 3 1 2`.

How can I get that index?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859261/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array and keep track of the index in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587314/how-to-sort-an-array-and-keep-track-of-the-index-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom comparator that sorts a list of indices, while comparing the double values in the original list.

Then create a new array, iterate over all indices and map the double values to the right location based on the index.

```
Integer[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, test.length).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

// indexes contains [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

Arrays.sort(indexes, Comparator.<Integer>comparingDouble(i -> test[i]).reversed());

// indexes is now [4, 0, 3, 1, 2].

// Now you can copy back into test:
test = IntStream.range(0, test.length).mapToObj(i -> test[i]).toArray(Double[]::new);
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Z1ANXz)

Comment: Two remarks: is it possible to do this using the base type `double` and `int` for the arrays? It would also be nice to sort the array itself rather than creating a copy?

Comment: The demo is also missing that last line!

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers in your array are distinct, you can use a `Map` to store the numbers as keys and their indices as values. Once the numbers are sorted, you can iterate the sorted array, retrieve the values from the `Map` by the number from each iteration and print them.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] test = { 7.0, 2.0, -5.0, 5.0, 9.0 };
        Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            map.put(test[i], i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(test, Collections.reverseOrder());

        // Display indices
        for (Double n : test) {
            System.out.print(map.get(n) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4 0 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your values are distinct (as in your example), an alternative is to use the `List.indexOf()` method which finds the index of a particular object.

```
Double[] test = {7.0, 2.0, -5.0, 5.0, 9.0};
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(test));
Arrays.sort(test, Collections.reverseOrder());

// find the indices.           
int[] indices = Arrays.stream(test).mapToInt(ob->doubleList.indexOf(ob)).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

prints

```
[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
```