# Java: Sorting an array based on another array with indexOf method

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, lambda, comparator

I want to iterate through two arrays(A, B) based on the sorted order of another array(indexes), which is 10, 34, 32, 21 in this case.

```
String[] A: a, b, c, d
String[] B: e, f, g, h
int[] indexes: 10, 34, 32, 21
```

> Apology for the bad example here. I have updated the indexes array to clear the confusion.

**Expected Input and Output**

The input are the three arrays. I wanted to iterate through A, B using the sorted of the indexes array. i.e. I want to find a way to iterate A using the order (a, d, c, b) and iterate B using the order (e, h, g, f)

**My approach:**

I solved the problem with a solution that I believe is identical to another approach. However, the second approach **does not** work. I would appreciate if someone can explain why it does not work as I think it would give me a better understanding of how Collections.sort works in java.

```
List<Integer> indexOrder = new ArrayList<>(indexes.length);

for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    indexOrder.add(i);
}

Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[s]));
```

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859261/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting), I created an ArrayList (prefer AList not array) with value (1, 2, 3...indexes.length) and then sort it using a comparator with ref. to indexes. **The codes above work as expected.**

However, if I change the **indexes[s]** at the end of the last line to **indexes[indexOrder.indexOf(s)]**. The sorting will give a wrong result. Why is indexOf(s) giving a different result than s if the ArrayList's index is the same as its value.

```
Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[indexOrder.indexOf(s)]));
```

Comment: what is your input and expected output?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but why not simply `for (int idx : indexes) { ... A[idx] ... B[idx] ...}`

Comment: Do you have duplicates in `indexOrder` or is `indexOrder` sparse?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated the expected input and output. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: No, there is not duplicates in indexOrder. Its values are just 0, 1, 2, 3... indexes.length.

Comment: Are all three arrays the same length?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes, the three arrays are of same length.

Comment: I think Eran gave the right answer (possibly the others too, but I haven't looked at them). However, I would use an array rather than an ArrayList in this case. An `ArrayList<Integer>` takes up more than 3 times the space of `int[]`, and doesn't give any advantage at all in terms of increased readability to compensate for the extra space & time.

Comment: @Andyk.I've updated with a fast solution based on QuickSort algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you expect `indexOrder.indexOf(s)` to always be equal to `s` (since your `List` was initialized to `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, where the index of `s` is `s`).

While this is true in your original `indexOrder` `List`, this may no longer true when `Collections.sort` starts swapping elements of your `List`.

In order not to rely on the ordering of `indexOrder` while you are sorting it, you can create a copy of that `List`:

```
List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(indexOrder);
Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[copy.indexOf(s)]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the maximum value stored in indexes won't exceed 1000 i feel like an implementation of this sorting algorithm (which is a variant of the counting sort) will be the best choice.

```
final String[] A = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
final String[] B = { "e", "f", "g", "h" };
final int[] indexes =  { 10, 34, 32, 21 };

// find out the max value in the array.
// The loop can be skipped with maxIndexValue = 1000; but i would most likely save some memory using the loop.
// Can also be replaced with : IntStream.of(indexes).max().getAsInt(), with such a small set of data it won't hurt performance that bad
int maxIndexValue = 0;
for (int indexValue: indexes) {
    if (maxIndexValue < indexValue) {
        maxIndexValue = indexValue;
    }
}
maxIndexValue += 1;

final String[] indexSortedA = new String[maxIndexValue];
final String[] indexSortedB = new String[maxIndexValue];
System.out.println(maxIndexValue);
// each value of A (and B) will be put at indexes position, it will result in a appropriately sorted arrays but with a lot of whitespace.
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
    indexSortedA[indexes[i]] = A[i];
    indexSortedB[indexes[i]] = B[i];
}

// Create final arrays by filtering empty values
final String[] sortedA = Arrays.stream(indexSortedA).filter(v -> v != null && !"".equals(v)).toArray(String[]::new);
final String[] sortedB = Arrays.stream(indexSortedB).filter(v -> v != null && !"".equals(v)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Complexity of this algorithm will be : O(n) + O(1000) + O(2n). It will be better nthan any `Collection.sort()` but it cost a bit more memory.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I realized that my example of indexes array was making a confusion that indexes can be used directly for sorting but it's not the case.

Comment: Ow indeed. Are the numbers known to be in a short interval or it can be the whole Interger range?

Comment: The range of the numbers is as follows. `0 < indexes[i] <= 1000`

Comment: @Andyk.I've updated my answer according to this constraint

Comment: Love how you approached the question. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I see how this works and should be quite fast. By the way, a possible way to get the max index value more consisely (and probably more readable): `final int maxIndexValue = IntStream.of(indexes).max().getAsInt();`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes indeed, i added it to the example along with a warning about the fact that i cost more time to perform that a regular for loop. It's sad that streams are slower than regular loops... So i try to use them only when the readability is greatly improved.

Comment: Indeed, stream operations are slower than raw loops over primitive arrays. However, the JIT can make this difference minimal; and if the relevant piece of code isn't JITed it's because it hasn't been run enough times to make much difference anyway. In [Angelika Langer's study](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html) stream operations took 15 times longer than raw loops over an array of int, but this was without a warm-up (i.e. no JIT). So in such a case, what difference does 15 microseconds vs 1 microsecond make? Both are blindingly fast.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yep, probably not a big deal for such small sets of data.

Comment: In fact, once the Stream operations get JITed, using Streams appears to be FASTER than using loops! See https://ideone.com/Qnwo8j

Comment: Wow, impressive, didn't knew that it scale that much with JIT. Good to know :)

Comment: I think your algorithm is a variant of [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) with the count being either 0 or 1 (since there are no duplicates).

Comment: That's it ! I could not remember the name. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to ran both the code and I get the same result in both the cases.

Case 1 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] A = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
    String[] B = { "e", "f", "g", "h" };
    int[] indexes = { 0, 4, 2, 1 };

    List<Integer> indexOrder = new ArrayList<>(indexes.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        indexOrder.add(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    //Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[s]));
    Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[indexOrder.indexOf(s)]));

    System.out.println(indexOrder.toString());
}
```

Ouput : 
0
1
2
3

[0, 3, 2, 1]

Case 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] A = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
    String[] B = { "e", "f", "g", "h" };
    int[] indexes = { 0, 4, 2, 1 };

    List<Integer> indexOrder = new ArrayList<>(indexes.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        indexOrder.add(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[s]));
    //Collections.sort(indexOrder, Comparator.comparing((Integer s) -> indexes[indexOrder.indexOf(s)]));

    System.out.println(indexOrder.toString());
}
```

output : 
0
1
2
3

[0, 3, 2, 1]