# How to print sorted array index instead of the value in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

```
int[] array = new int[3];
    array[0] = 3;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 4;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length;i++){
        for(int j = i+1 ; j< array.length;j++){
            if(array[i] < array[j]){
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
}
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

So for example in this I have the code printing out the array values from highest to lowest(4,3,2). However what I would like it to do is print the index/position of the array instead(2,0,1). Can't quite seem to figure it out myself, fairly new to this.

Comment: if you want to print index then just print i

Comment: Similar to: [get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859261/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting)

Comment: You are sorting the array and then printing it.  You probably don't want to change the state of the array like that.  See @PiotrMichalczyk comment for a better approach.

Comment: For what I am doing I do want to change the state of my array to the index value instead @vsfDAWG

Comment: Map the array to an array of pairs of (value, index), sort based on the value, then map back to an array of the indices. Aka Swartzian Tranform.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*you can create a new class lik that :*/

    public class IndexAndValue {
      int index, value; 
     public IndexAndValue(int index ,int value){
       this.index =index ;
       this.value = value ;
     }
    }


  IndexAndValue[] array = new IndexAndValue[3];  
    array[0] = new IndexAndValue(0 ,2);
    array[1] = new IndexAndValue(1 ,2);
    array[2] = new IndexAndValue(2 ,4);

   for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length;i++){
        for(int j = i+1 ; j< array.length;j++){
            if(array[i].value < array[j].value){
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("Index : " +array[i].index +" value: " +array[i].value);
    }

/*
whene you exucte this you get :
"Index : 2 value: 4"
"Index : 0 value: 3"
"Index : 1 value: 2"
*/
```