# Sort ArrayList A based on ArrayList B

Tags: java

Say for example I have:

> **ArrayList A;** with values: "a","b", "c", "d", "e"
>
> **ArrayList B**; with values: "3","1", "5", "2", "4"

Then I performed

> Collections.sort(B);

so then **ArrayList B** becomes:

> "1","2", "3", "4", "5"

Now I want to sort **ArrayList A** based on the sort in **ArrayList B**, I should get **ArrayListA**:

> "b","d", "a", "e", "c"

How can I achieve that? Sorry I'm still new to Android. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Android API does not provide anyhing out of the box to achieve that.  You'll need to write some code to handle the necessary logic.

Comment: I don't understand your example. How is A being sorted using B? Also, this doesn't have to do with Android.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4839994/3558960). And also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4841110/3558960) is relevant.

Comment: That is nothing to do with android. It's pure logic thing which you have to manipulate in your code yourself.

Comment: Just like @wdosanjos said, android API does not provide method to achieve that, which answers my question. I'll just proceed to manual/procedural approach to achieve what I want. I'll just update OP asap.

Comment: Btw @Clairvoyant I'm no new to programming/logics, but I'm new to Android, and I'm asking if there's an Android API for what I want to achieve. You can comment appropriately.

Comment: I do appologize if my comment was rude. But have you tried yourself before asking that question??? Because if i am at your place i would first search myself, show my effort what i have did till now.

Comment: I am removing the android tags, because this has nothing to do with android, it has to do with basic java. You need to figure out how to either user comparators or use what @MirMasej recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the data into the `TreeMap` (which is a map sorted by natural ordering of its keys) and you're done.

Manual approach (if you want some programming practice) would be:

- put both lists in a single map where keys come from list B and values from list A
- get the keys from map and sort them
- iterate over sorted keys and get values from the map and put them into new list.

As you can see this question has nothing to do with Android, it's just a simple programming task.

Comment: I think "key sorted" would be a better term than "map sorted," but that's a bit of a nitpick. +1